ODOO 14 - Update view (model data) from controller
I have my class
class Residencia(models.Model):
    _name = "residencia"
    _description = "Residencia"

    name = fields.Char(string='Nombre', required=True)
    gateway_id = fields.Char(string='Gateway ID', required=False)
    gateway_id_config = fields.Char(string='Gateway ID Config', required=False)
    oxeen_products = fields.Selection([
        ('paciente_enfermera', 'Paciente Enfermera'),
        ('errantes', 'Control de Errantes'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    ], string='Productos OXEEN', required=True, default='paciente_enfermera')

    note = fields.Text(string='Descripción')
    mqtt_path = fields.Text(string='MQTT Path')
    mqtt_active = fields.Boolean(string="Activar escucha MQTT", default=False)
    mqtt_new_message = fields.Boolean(string="New Message", default=False)
    residencia_oxeen_callbuttons = fields.One2many('residencia.oxeen.callbutton', 'patient_id', string="Oxeen Call Buttons")
    id = fields.Integer(string="ID")
    total_callbuttons = fields.Integer(string="Total Call Buttons", compute='_compute_total_callbuttons', store=True)
    reload_trigger = fields.Integer(compute='_compute_reload_trigger', store=True)

    @api.depends('reload_trigger')
    def _compute_reload_trigger(self):
        for record in self:
            record.reload_trigger += 1

and I have my controller :
class MQTTController(http.Controller):
    @http.route('/api/mqtt/handle', type='json', auth='public', methods=['POST'], csrf=False)
    def handle_mqtt_message(self, **kwargs):
        ....
        
        residencia = request.env['residencia'].sudo().browse(residencia_id)
        if residencia.exists():
            new_value = not residencia.mqtt_new_message
            residencia.write({'mqtt_new_message': new_value})

            # Create a new oxeen call button
            call_button_data = {
                'caller_name': f'New Caller Name {residencia_id}',
                'caller_id': f'New Caller ID {residencia_id}',
                'patient_id': residencia.id,
            }
            request.env['residencia.oxeen.callbutton'].sudo().create(call_button_data)
            #Here I try to update the model (view)
            residencia.reload_trigger += 1   
            # request.env['ir.config_parameter'].sudo().set_param('oxeen.refresh_needed', '1')
            return {'success': 'Message handled and flag set'}

I'm trying to update the view by updating the model from the controller but I see no effect. Anyone could help? I tried that following that topic: https://www.odoo.com/es_ES/forum/ayuda-1/odoo-14-model-is-not-updating-via-controller-185038

Hi, Which change do you expect in your view ? Which View ? By the way, your controller does not render a view but dictionary...
